# R Programming: Package DEoptim Returning Inconsistent Results

Tags: r, optimization, numerical-methods, quantitative-finance, portfolio

I am running a portfolio optimization using the DEoptim to minimize the inverse of the Sharpe ratio, which is the same as maximizing the Sharpe ratio. However, I am receiving inconsistent results as to what is the vector of the weights that can be used to maximize my Sharpe.

```
  # Computing the covariance matrix and returns to be used in the optimization
  covMat <- cov(dft[idx_window_begin:idx_window_end,returns])
  Returns <- colMeans(dft[idx_window_begin:idx_window_end,returns])
  
  # Sharpe ratio function to be used in the DEoptim function
  port_sharpe <- function(W) {
    W <- W/sum(W)
    return(as.numeric((W%*%covMat%*%W)^0.5/(W%*%Returns)))
  }
  
  # Calling DEoptim
  sol <- DEoptim(port_sharpe, lower=rep(-100,nrow(covMat)), upper=rep(100,nrow(covMat)))
```

I was expecting the same vector of weights to be returned each time i.e. sol$optim$bestmem should return the same vector of weights for all runs.

Comment: DEOptim is a stochastic heuristic. Max Sharpe Ratio can be reformulated as a convex QP model, and solved deterministically using a QP solver.

Comment: Hi @ErwinKalvelagen, thanks for your inputs. Are you saying that DEoptim is not suitable for maximizing the Sharpe in R?

Comment: No, that is not what I am saying.

Comment: But you mentioned using a QP solver (I suppose this is from a different package), doesn't that mean we are moving away from using DEoptim? And can you elaborate more on why a stochastic heuristic algorithm is not suitable for maximizing the Sharpe?

Comment: Yes, if you want deterministic results (each time exactly the same solution), I would use a deterministic solver. If you are happy with a good solution (can vary run after run), use a stochastic heuristic.